# Would Tonks' metamorphic capabilities make her a "natural" animagus?

Tags: harry-potter, magic, magical-theory, shape-shifter

Is Tonks ability limited in that she can't transform into a full animal the way other animagi can?

If not, what's the difference?

Further more, considering *both* his parents' have transformative capabilities, does that mean Teddy Lupin has a higher chance of inheriting shape-shifting magic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Metamorphmagi can only change their appearance - they cannot naturally transform into another species.

As Tonks explained to Harry, Metamorphmagi can change their appearances at will. This is almost certainly limited to human features, however.

> “How did you do that?’ said Harry, gaping at her as she opened her eyes again.
>
> **‘I’m a Metamorphmagus,’** she said, looking back at her reflection and turning her head so that she could see her hair from all directions. **‘It means I can change my appearance at will,’** she added, spotting Harry’s puzzled expression in the mirror behind her. ‘I was born one. I got top marks in Concealment and Disguise during Auror training without any study at all, it was great.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 3 (The Advance Guard)*</sup></sub>

While she can give herself features that resemble those of animals, such as a nose that looks like a pig snout, she would not be able to turn completely into a pig. Her pig nose made her look like a female Dudley, implying that it’s not actually a snout but instead the closest to a pig nose that a human nose can get.

> “Opposite Harry, Tonks was entertaining Hermione and Ginny by transforming her nose between mouthfuls. Screwing up her eyes each time with the same pained expression she had worn back in Harry’s bedroom, her nose swelled to a beak-like protuberance that resembled Snape’s, shrank to the size of a button mushroom and then sprouted a great deal of hair from each nostril. Apparently this was a regular mealtime entertainment, because Hermione and Ginny were soon requesting their favourite noses.
>
> ‘Do that one like a pig snout, Tonks.’
>
> Tonks obliged, and Harry, looking up, had the fleeting impression that a female Dudley was grinning at him from across the table.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 5 (The
> Order of the Phoenix)*</sup></sub>

There is no evidence that Tonks’s natural ability to change her appearance would make it easier for her to become an Animagus. Becoming an Animagus does not seem to be closely connected enough to changing appearance within a human form for it to give her any advantage.

> “Animagi make up a small fraction of the Wizarding population. Achieving perfect, spontaneous human-to-animal transformation requires much study and practice, and many witches and wizards consider that their time might be better employed in other ways.” 
> <sub><sup>*- The Tales of Beedle the Bard*</sup></sub>

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as "natural" animagus. Becoming an animagus is a long process which includes several steps including holding the leaf of a mandrake in your mouth for an entire month, using the leaf for the creation of a potion, reciting an incantation, "Amato Animo Animato Animagus" on a daily basis, and drinking the Animagus potion during a lightning storm.

As for metamorphmagi, it is not a skill that can be learned – one has to be born with it. It is never stated in the books (or movies for that matter) that a metamorphmagus can completely morph into an animal like an animagus can. As far as we know, they can only change their appearance.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 mechanisms at work.  Tonk's ability is inherited.  It's Genetic.  Where Lupin is a Werewolf.  He is not even an Animagus.  It's not a benign transformation, it is the result of a curse, or cursed magic.

The inheritance and genetic properties of the Werewolf curse is not explained.  That means it would be up to the author to use it in any way they wanted to.  They could make Teddy Grow a waggy tail a few nights a month.  Or make him transform into the furry animal of choice once a month.  Perhaps his mother's genetics means he could change from one creature to another but only while transformed by the light of the full moon.  Narratively, it's wide open.

I would say that inheriting the abilities of a metamorphmagi is more straightforward.  It is an extremely rare recessive gene, like having Violet colored eyes.  Cross interaction is entirely a matter of speculation.

Being a Metamorphmagi is not a mechanism to transforming into an animal, as far as it is explained.  The magic in becoming an Animagus actually fully transforms one into the animal.  McGonagel changes fully into a house cat.  James turned himself into a Stag, while Wormtail went into a small rat.  All of those involve a significant change in Mass.  I don't see anything in the way Tonk's powers were depicted that she was able to alter mass or major body structure.  This is not from any Canon I have seen, just from what I have read and the way my brain works.

Comment: You make a lot of good points. Thank you for your input there in.